# How to develop an Screen-Lock/Unlock functionality in my application in Android?

Tags: android

actually i am developing one application...in my application i am trying to develop screen-lock n unlock application functionality..
So please help me to develop it...

Thanks in Advance--

Comment: You want to popup after every 2sec. But till how much time ?..It goes infinite ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Handler.postDelayed()** method in order to perform this. Just call the handler on click of that button.
See the following code:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {   // mHandler is the instance of the Handler class 

  @Override
  public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
//Perform your action //here                                                                                            
    }
},1000L); //time in milisecond here
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nopes i want to call activity automatically after some time..(Ex. after every 2sec.)..can it is possible??

Comment: ya why not not do the same thing outsode the onClick method , i.e. just within the onCreate method.Try to do the whole work within a Thread and then start the Thread.